# Extract content of Zip file after reading Zip file from Exchange server through JavaMail

Tags: java, zip, jakarta-mail, unzip

Here is the program which reads the content of a ZIP file.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm

But my problem here is this line : ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("C:/ReadZip.zip");

In above ZipFile constructor it is passing path of the ZIP file.

In my case I don't have that ZIP file stored anywhere. In my case I am first reading that ZIP file from the exchange email account through JavaMail API and then I need to read the content of that ZIP file.

Through JavaMail I am able to connect to exchange and read the email and extract the attachment and then see if that attachment is a zip file - all that is working - now I have the zip file - how I dynamically pass to ZipFile constructor  ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("C:/ReadZip.zip");

Really appreciate your help in this. I need to get this done over the weekend.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you extract the zip file?

If it's in the same directory as your project, you can simply use relative path.

Example: ZipFile a = new ZipeFile("zipefile.zip");

If you created a separate folder within the project directory,

```
     ZipeFile a = new ZipFile("filename/zipfile.zip");
```

Comment: I cannot use this - new ZipeFile("zipefile.zip"); as I don't have zip file stored in hard disk. I read zip file from exchange server through JavaMail and now I need to pass that ZipFile in above constructor.

Comment: When you say "I read zip file from exchange server", what do you **do** with the zip file when you read it?  If you use the MimeBodyPart.saveFile method to save it to a temporary file, you can pass that file name as described above.  Otherwise, try using ZipInputStream to wrap the InputStream that comes from MimeBodyPart.getInputStream.  See the javadocs for details on all these methods and classes.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the zip file you get from JavaMail API is through an input stream, you can use [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read the contents of the zip file. An example of ZipInputStream is [here](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-decompress-a-zip-file-using-zipinputstream/)